# How to make TCP receive to process asynchronous(or no-echo) client?

Tags: http, tcp, nginx

I have write a simple HTTP server based on Webdis. Now I got a problem that while a client send HTTP request without receive response(AKA, only send, not receive response from server), the server will receive multiple HTTP requests, and this will cause the parse module fail(may be this is a bug in the parse module). If any fuzzy, comes some of my code:

```
/* client... */
int fd = connect_server();
while (1) {
    send(fd, buf, sz);
    continue; /* no receive.. */        
}

/* server... */
/* some event trigger following code */
char buffer[4096]; /* a stack based receive buffer, buggy */
ret = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

while client send 10 HTTP request(less than 4096 bytes) during server's sleep(for debug), this the next receive will receive 10 request one a time, but the parser can not parse multiple request, this make all these request fail. If all these request larger than 4096, this will cut off one of them and still fail.

I have browsed Nginx source code, may it was *callback designed*(not blame), I haven't got its solution...

---

Is there any way to do following things:

*How to control the `recv` call that only receive only one request a time? Or is there some TCP related mechanism that makes it possible to receive only one `send` request?*

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with synchronousness or events, but with the streaming nature of such sockets. *You* will have to buffer previously received data and you will have to implement certain parts of HTTP in its entirety in order to be able to mark an incoming request as complete, after which you can release it from your buffer and start parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is by definition stream-based, so you can never be guaranteed that message borders will be respeted. Strictly speaking, such a thing do not exist in TCP. However, using blocking-sockets and making sure that Nagle's algorithm is disabled, reduces the chance of each recv() containing more than one segment. Just for testing, you could also insert a sleep after each send(). You could also play around with TCP_CORK.

However, instead of hacking something together, I would recomend you implement receiving "properly", as you will have to do it at some point. For each recv-call, check if the buffer contains the end of an HTTP-request (\r\n\r\n), and then process.